# Efficiently set categories of multiple posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to migrate large amounts of data from a non-WP-like CMS into WordPress and I'm trying to find an efficient way to assign batches of posts to a category.
`wp_set_post_categories()` takes a single post and an array of categories to add it to. Is there anything more efficient than simply looping through an array of post id's and calling `wp_set_post_categories()` on each one with a call to the database each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option may be to run a SQL query to set the category on all of the posts in one go.

```
global $wpdb;
$category = get_category(get_query_var('category'));
$term_taxonomy_id = $category->term_taxonomy_id;
$wpdb->query("
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->term_relationships
    ( object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order )
    SELECT
        ID AS object_id,
        $term_taxonomy_id AS term_taxonomy_id,
        0 AS term_order
    FROM
        $wpdb->posts
");
```

Update: then to update the field that counts the number of posts the category has.

```
$wpdb->query("
    UPDATE $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    SET `count` = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM wp_posts)
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $term_taxonomy_id
");
```

Comment: This will assign the same category to all of my posts but it seems trivial or at least simple to select the posts I want for each category given an array of post ids